# I need to conditionally fill a new column in a dataframe based on the values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

As you will understand I am pretty new to pandas and I have found myself stuck with the below problem.
Lets say I have the below Facebook data ( I have completely randomised them by the way for the sake of the example):

```
        Ad Set Name                             Impresions Link Clicks
0   253-Page.Visitors.10.Days                       100       3
1   254-Cart.Abandoners.10.Days                     300       9
2   253-Page.Visitors.10.Days                       900       27
3   256-LAL.5%.Add.to.Cart                        2,700       81
4   256-LAL.5%.Freq.Visits                        8,100       243
5   254-Cart.Abandoners.10.Days                   24,300      729
6   254-Cart.Abandoners.10.Days                   72,900      2,187
```

Now what I want to do is to create a new column called 'audience' and populate it based on these 3 conditions:

- if the column 'Ad Set Name' contains the word 'Page.Visitors' the respective cell in the new column audience should be populated with 'Page Visitors'
- If it contains 'Cart.Abandoners' it should be populated with 'Cart Abandoners'
- And finally, if it contains 'LAL' it should be populated with 'Lookalikes'

This is how I tried to do it:

```
for i in data['Ad Set Name']:
    if 'Page.Visitors' in i:
        data.loc[i,'audiience'] = 'Page Visitors'
    elif 'Cart.Abandoners' in i:
        data.loc[i,'audience'] = 'Cart Abandoners'
    else:
        data.loc[i,'audience'] = 'Lookalikes'
data.head()
```

but the column I get back is filled with NaN.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at numpy.where - https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Comment: Thanks, guys a lot guys.
So I think numpy.where will work only if I have two choices right? 

@DavideFiocco yes the provided answer helps, as it has some useful solutions like the numpy.select that is also mentioned in this thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can do numpy.select

```
conditions = [
    (df["Ad Set Name"].str.contains("Page.Visitors")),
    (df["Ad Set Name"].str.contains("Cart.Abandoners")),
]

choices = ["Page Visitors", "Cart Abandoners"]

df["audience"] = numpy.select(conditions, choices, default="Office - Lookalikes")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! It works really fine with the np.select!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the following:
First you need to import numpy:

```
import numpy as np
```

Then set the column audience to nans udn fill it with your data like this

```
df['audiience'] =np.nan
df.loc[df[df['Ad Set Name'].str.contains('Page.Visitors', regex=False)==True].index, 'audiience'] = 'Page Visitors'
df.loc[df[df['Ad Set Name'].str.contains('Cart.Abandoners', regex=False)==True].index, 'audiience'] = 'Cart Abandoners'
df.loc[df[df['Ad Set Name'].str.contains('LAL', regex=False)==True].index, 'audiience'] = 'Lookalikes'
```

this will give you the following dataframe:

```
Ad Set Name                  Impresions Link Clicks audiience
0   253-Page.Visitors.10.Days       100     3       Page Visitors
1   254-Cart.Abandoners.10.Days     300     9       Cart Abandoners
2   253-Page.Visitors.10.Days       900     27      Page Visitors
3   256-LAL.5%.Add.to.Cart         2700     81      Lookalikes
4   256-LAL.5%.Freq.Visits         8100     243     Lookalikes
5   254-Cart.Abandoners.10.Days   24300     729     Cart Abandoners
6   254-Cart.Abandoners.10.Days   72900     2187    Cart Abandoners
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this! I tried applying this method but it gives me back the error "list index out of range"

Answer (score 0):

Also, another user had initially provided the below answer which for some reason I can see now is deleted.
This also worked perfectly and was also very easy for me (that I am a newbie in pandas) to read and  understand:

```
def replace_ad_set(text):
    if "Page.Visitors" in text:
        return "Page Visitors"
    elif 'Cart.Abandoners' in text:
        return "Cart Abandoners"
    elif "LAL" in text:
        return "Lookalikes"

data["audience"] = data["Ad Set Name"].apply(replace_ad_set)

data
```